# python instances to string its representation

Tags: python

I have many composed objects like `A.elem1.elem2`,`B.elem3.elem0` which are generated dynamically, thanks to an XML schema.
I would like to find a way to convert an object like this to its exact string representation, so let's say I have

```
>>> v=A.elem1.elem2
>>> w=B.elem0
```

then I would like to have

```
[In]: >>> print(v.toString())
"A.elem1.elem2"
[In]: >>> print(w.toString())
"B.elem0"
```

I dont know any smart way doing this, except override by hand `__repr__` and `__str__` in each one of hundreds objects...  There must be a better way?

Comment: How should `v` know that it belongs to `elem1`, and that that belonged to `A`, and what was the name of `A` in the first place? Depending on the XML lib you use, there might be a function to find the path to `v` (which seems what you want) but I don't see how you could do this from `v` alone.

Comment: XML schema knows it. But that's my question

Comment: Interesting problem, but you have to post more contextual information, at least a sample XML file and the lib and code you are using to extract `v`, otherwise we can't help.